# International Electrical Certification

Tags: certification

I am involved in a project where we will be doing a run of about 200 products. We do not know where in the world our client will be sending these products.

Each product uses mostly off the shelf electronics:

[orange pi](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/)

[12V power supply](http://www.meanwell.com/productSeries.aspx?i=16&c=6#tag-6-16) (taking mains power)

[touch screen](https://www.robotics.org.za/AF1676?search=touch%20screen)

[DC-DC converter](http://www.communica.co.za/Catalog/Details/P4138706545)

[Arcade buttons](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/led-arcade-button)

The only piece of custom hardware is a simple transistor circuit for each arcade button to turn on the LED.

My concern for the project, is the red tape when taking the project to different countries. What kind of certification would I need?

Comment: That's not your problem.

Comment: Let's please assume that it is my problem. Obviously it's possible for me to shift the responsibility to my client, but there is a likelihood that I would have to organise this for them. Surely this question is answerable?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be your client's problem. It is for them to specify the standards to which the product will be built and certified - you cannot be expected to anticipate what they will do with the product, unless that is part of the design specification.

As a general piece of advice, always generate a complete specification for any project - and make sure the client approves it in writing. That way you can prove you met the client's requirements, and any omission or error is not your liability.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, it is the client's responsibility to identify the markets that you will need to plan for.

I will suggest, though, that if your client is particularly unhelpful and you need a place to start, you can look into a [CB scheme](https://www.iecee.org/about/cb-scheme/) for designing for safety purposes.  This at least has some semblance of multi-national acceptance.